# Ubuntu 1604: Software installation/Squirrel shell/synkron

Tags: software-installation

File downloaded and extracted: squirrelsh-1.2.7-src.tar.bz2
Output folder: squirrelsh-1.2.7
Squirrel manual says to run command : sh squirrelsh-1.2.7.run
But I did not find any file with this name.
How to install squirrel shell so as to install synkron?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't download the pre-compiled version of the shell, so you need to follow the 2nd option.

For source code archive:

> 1. Unpack archive to a directory accessible during compilation.    Make sure that directories structure is preserved.
> 2. Run `./configure` to create makefiles. Run `./configure --help` to see    information about supported compilation options.
> 3. If configuration process completed successfully, run `make` to compile    Squirrel Shell.
> 4. Run `make install` to install Squirrel Shell on your computer. You may need    root privileges to perform this step.

Comment: OK, let me try.